# Updating multiple attribute fields in metadata XML with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, xml, metadata

Updating multiple field attributes through Python in an XML metadata doc export. There are multiple fields, so the XML tags for each unique field are all the same:

```
      <attr>
        <attrlabl>STATE_NAME</attrlabl>
        <attrdef>State Name</attrdef>
        <attrdefs>HRSA GDW</attrdefs>
        <attrdomv>
          <udom>2010</udom>
        </attrdomv>
      </attr>
      <attr>
        <attrlabl>County</attrlabl>
        <attrdef>County Name</attrdef>
        <attrdefs>HRSA GDW</attrdefs>
        <attrdomv>
          <udom>2010</udom>
        </attrdomv>
      </attr>
      <attr>
        <attrlabl>STCOFIPS</attrlabl>
        <attrdef>State/County FIPS ID</attrdef>
        <attrdefs>HRSA GDW</attrdefs>
        <attrdomv>
          <udom>2010</udom>
        </attrdomv>
      </attr>
```

How do I call each unique field out in a python script to update the metadata in an XML. This is where I am:

```
import arcpy, sys  
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree  
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement  
from arcpy import env  
env.overwriteOutput = True  
fcpath = r""
translatorpath = r"...\Metadata\Translator\ARCGIS2FGDC.xml"
xmlfile = r"...\FullMetaFC.xml"
arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(fcpath, translatorpath, xmlfile)

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(xmlfile)

ele = tree.find("eainfo/detailed")
for e in ele.iter("attrlabl"):
    # loop through children pulling out nodes which have a attrlabl tag
    print e.text
    # do some sort if IF THEN logic check and update as necessary
    if e.text == "STATE_NAME":
        ele.iter("attrdefs") = "NAME OF THE STATE"

tree.write(xmlfile)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to call the save method on tree to commit the change. Search python help on XML to understand the syntax used.

Comment: I have added in the save method, but it's still not committing the change to the field attributes. I tested with other elements and those fields update just fine. I suspect the issue is with the IF/THEN statement, but can't figure it out without an error

Comment: I have updated my answer, your were traversing the tree structure a level too low for for iter() to pick up the correct level.

Comment: Added the code updates to the script and it produces an error that: Runtime error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Check your spelling if NoneType is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Although your XML is derived from a spatial dataset metadata, this question is not really about GIS but about traversing an XML file. That said I think you need to grab the Element one level higher so you have a branch of it with all your child nodes then step through those "children" doing some sort of if/then logic check and updating as necessary.

*Generic Example*

```py
import arcpy, sys
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
xmlfile = r"C:\Scratch\aaa.xml"
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(xmlfile)

ele = tree.find("eainfo/detailed")
for e in ele.iter("attrlabl"):
    # loop through children pulling out nodes which have a attrlabl tag
    print e.text
    # do some sort if IF THEN logic check and update as necessary
```

*Specific Example using your data*

```py
import arcpy, sys
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
xmlfile = r"C:\Scratch\aaa.xml"
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(xmlfile)
ele = tree.find("eainfo/detailed")
for e in ele.iter("attr"):

    # do some sort if IF THEN logic check and update as necessary
    if e.find("attrlabl").text == "STATE_NAME":
        e.find("attrdefs").text = "NAME OF THE STATE"

tree.write(xmlfile)
```

Comment: Adding your helper code along with an IF/THEN doesn't produce any errors nor does it update the text:

if e.text == "STATE_NAME":
        ele.iter("attrdefs") = "NAME OF THE STATE"

Comment: I was providing you a pointer to how to navigate the xlm dom. You have to save your changes. If you have amended your code and using save then suggest you edit your question and show the additional code?

Comment: Added the amended part of the code